# ¿Como hacer un map en el array cargado en el useState retornando objetos en React?

Tags: react-hooks

En el **useState** tengo cargado un **array de objetos** con esta estructura:

```js
[
  {
    "id_operation": 4,
    "user_email": "lau@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de clase de ingles",
    "amount": "1500",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "egreso",
    "category": 1,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 5,
    "user_email": "good2021@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de sueldo ",
    "amount": "80000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "egreso",
    "category": 2,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 7,
    "user_email": "ab2021@gmail.com",
    "concept": "Cobro de sueldo",
    "amount": "70000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "ingreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "id_operation": 9,
    "user_email": "baty@gmail.com",
    "concept": "cobro de sueldo",
    "amount": "70000",
    "date": "2021-04-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "ingreso",
    "category": 4,
    "state": true
  },
]
```

Estos datos los muestro en una **tabla**. Lo que quiero hacer es un **filtrado** **sobre este array de objetos que esta en el useState**,seteando el estado con los objetos que cumplan con la condicion del filtrado y mostrarlos en la tabla.
El filtrado es solo por tipo, o por tipo y categoria al mismo tiempo, es decir:
si por ejemplo en el select de tipo de operacion se elige **"ingreso"**, **devuelva todos los objetos que sean de tipo operacion ingreso**. **Si ademas se elige una categoria, devolveria por tipo y categoria**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El **boton search** en el **evento onClick** llama a una **funcion filter()**,
esta funcion toma las opciones elegidas de los **select** (hasta este punto lo hice bien) pero
necesito que el **map** me **devuelva los objetos**. De la forma que lo hice no funciona.
No quiero marearlos con el codigo porque lo que me faltaria es que en la funcion **filter()**,
el **map devuelva los objetos segun el filtrado**. De todos modos les muestro todo el codigo:

```js
const OperationsList = (props) => {
  const [stateOperations, setStateOperations] = React.useState([]);
  const [checkCat, setCheckCat] = React.useState(false); // estado del checkbox de categoria
  const [type, setType] = React.useState("ingreso"); // valor del select type
  const [stateCategory, setStateCategory] = React.useState(1); // valor del select category
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setStateOperations(props.operations);
  }, [props.operations]);

  const filter = (e) => {

    // si el checkbox de categoria esta en true
    if(checkCat){
      alert('filtra por categoria y tipo')
      console.log('TYPE: ' + type);
      console.log('CATEGORIA: ' + stateCategory);
      
      setStateOperations(stateOperations.map(item => item.category === stateCategory && item.type === type));
    }
    else{
      alert('filtra solo por tipo');
      console.log('SOLO TYPE: ' + type);
      setStateOperations(stateOperations.map(item => item.type === type));     
     
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div id="box-check">
        <div className="d-flex mb-3">
          <Form.Check label="Tipo:" checked className="mt-1" />
          <select
            className="form-select"
            value={type}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const selectedType = e.target.value;
              setType(selectedType);
            }}
          >
            <option value="ingreso">Ingreso</option>
            <option value="egreso">Egreso</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex">
          <Form.Check
            className="mt-1"
            label="Categoria:"
            checked={checkCat}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCheckCat(!checkCat);
            }}
          />
          <select
            // se muestra cuando el check category esta checked
            hidden={!checkCat}
            className="form-select"
            onChange={(e) => {
              const selectedCategory = e.target.value;
              setStateCategory(selectedCategory);
            }}
          >
            {props.categories.map((item) => (
              <option key={item.id} value={item.name}>
                {item.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div> 
        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={filter}>search</button>
      </div>

      <div className="table-responsive">
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Concepto</th>
              <th>Monto</th>
              <th>Tipo</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {stateOperations.map((item) => (
              <tr key={cont++}>
                <td>
                  {moment(item.registration_date)
                    .subtract(10, "days")
                    .calendar()}
                </td>
                <td>{item.concept}</td>
                <td>{item.amount}</td>
                <td>{item.type}</td>
                <td>{item.category}</td>
                <div className="text-center">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
                  </button>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </Fragment> 
  );  
};
```

Comment: estas utilizando un `map` para filtrar datos, deberías utilizar un `filter` como buena practica, prueba utilizando esto `setStateOperations(prev => prev.filter(item => item.category === stateCategory && item.type === type));`

Comment: cuando intentas filtra los datos los `alert` que muestran aparecen ?

Comment: proba quitando el filtrado de los condicionales, si de esta manera el estado se cambia podrías agregar una función para los filtrados por tipo y para categorías omitiendo los condicionales

Comment: tuve errores parecidos e incluyendo condicionales, donde los condicionales me daban errores, fue por eso que sugerí quitar los condicionales para descartarlos del problema, la verdad que es muy raro que no se vuelva a renderizar tu componente siendo y cuando que estas actualizando el estado del mismo

Comment: @Enzo tenia un error que me acabo de dar cuenta, tu codigo esta bien, solo que tenia como value en el select el id de categoria, cuando tenia que poner el nombre de la categoria, por esa razon al hacer el filtro, estaba comparando el id con el nombre y por supuesto no habia coincidencia, asi que gracias y borro los comentarios de mas